# Output graph displaying an asterisk for each of integer stored in an array. starPrint maybe?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that creates ten random integers in an array, and then using each of these random integers, outputs asterix's to display the value of the integer.

For example, say these 10 integers where created at random by the program:

10,2,5,9,3,1,9,6,2,8

Currently the program will create these numbers and print them on the screen.

I want to add to the program code to print lines after the first line to give a result like this:

```
10 **********

2 **

5 *****

9 *********

3 ***

1 *

9 *********

6 ******

2 **

8 ********
```

I can't quite seem to work out how to get this to happen!

Here is my code:

```
public class randomnumbers {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    BufferedReader userInput =
                      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Random rand = new Random();
    int [] randInts = new int[10];
    int n = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < randInts.length; i++){
    randInts[i] = (1 + (Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) % n)) ;
    System.out.print(randInts[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();



    }

        }

    }
```

Any help anyone could give me with this would be much appreciated!!!

(There should be the same number of asterix as the value of the integer, but for some reason it is displaying strange on here, might just be my laptop though)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StringUtils.repeat(java.lang.String, int)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method from [Commons Lang API](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/index.html).

The sample based on your code:

```
public public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] randInts = new int[10];
    int max = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < randInts.length; i++) {
        randInts[i] = 1 + rand.nextInt(max);
        System.out.print(randInts[i] + " " + StringUtils.repeat("*", randInts[i]) + "\n");
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
10 ********** 
4 **** 
7 ******* 
3 *** 
1 * 
5 *****
3 *** 
10 ********** 
10 ********** 
10 **********
```